# Angular removes everything after & or %26 at url

Tags: angular, url, routes, components

I'm facing a problem with Angular. I'm trying to go to this URL http://serverurl/search/A&B but I don't know why something changes the url to http://serverurl/search/A also if I try to use the url encode for & it's the same problem
My routing component looks like this:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchComponent} from '../search/search.component';
         ...
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'search/:param',
    component: SearchComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Search Result',
      public: false,
      anchor: 'header'
   }
  }]
```

In local works fine but in dev server it is doing this behavior. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, please can you let me see how you are handling the routerlink? and also it seems your route is expecting only one parameter

Comment: what do you mean "handling the routerlink?" Yes A&B it is just an string that contains the character & so it has to be only 1 param.